# Retrieve information in previous tag with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having troble with a XML I need to transform woth xslt.

Here is my XML

```
<Groups>
            <term>
                <Tag1>My system1</Tag1>
                <Tag2>yes</Tag2>
                <Tag3>new york</Tag3>
            </term>
            <term>
                <Tag1/>
                <Tag2>no</Tag2>
                <Tag3>chicago</Tag3>
            </term>     
            <term>
                <Tag1>My system2</Tag1>
                <Tag2>ok</Tag2>
                <Tag3>paris</Tag3>
            </term>
            <term>
                <Tag1/>
                <Tag2>help</Tag2>
                <Tag3>london</Tag3>
            </term>
            <term>
                <Tag1/>
                <Tag2>cancel</Tag2>
                <Tag3>rome</Tag3>
            </term>
</Groups>
```

And here is my desired output.

```
<Groups>
            <term>
                <Tag1>My system1</Tag1>
                <Tag2>yes</Tag2>
                <Tag3>new york</Tag3>
            </term>
            <term>
                <Tag1>My system1</Tag1>
                <Tag2>no</Tag2>
                <Tag3>chicago</Tag3>
            </term>
            <term>
                <Tag1>My system2</Tag1>
                <Tag2>ok</Tag2>
                <Tag3>paris</Tag3>
            </term>
            <term>
                <Tag1>My system2</Tag1>
                <Tag2>help</Tag2>
                <Tag3>london</Tag3>
            </term>
            <term>
                <Tag1>My system2</Tag1>
                <Tag2>cancel</Tag2>
                <Tag3>rome</Tag3>
            </term>
</Groups>
```

All the xslt needs to do is to fill empty  tags with value from the previous non-empty  tags.

I tried using variable but apparently they do not work like variable in imperative languages.

Any advice on how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple stylesheet should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="*[not(text())]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::*[*[text() and name()=name(current())]][1]/*[text() and name()=name(current())]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, it help a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the 'preceding' axis to search for a corresponding tag that *does* contain a value, e.g. `preceding::Tag1[text()] [1]`. (select the first Tag1 element that has a text child, the first such tag will be the previous non-empty tag becaues the direction of the preceding axis is reverse document order). Clear?

Comment: That's ok, I bow to the elegance of the other answer and upvote that instead :)